# How to convert data received via modbus?

Tags: c#, modbus

I am getting data in my console program on **C#** with library `Nmodbus4` from a device via `modbus rtu`. **Format: 32 bit with floating point**. My answer is **17445**. But the expected value is **660**.

> How to convert the data and get 660 from 17445?

A little explanation would be nice!

```
using Modbus.Device;
using Modbus.Utility;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Elemer19
{ 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
            string[] pathFolder = ReadDirectory.readDir();
            Console.WriteLine("OPENING COM PORT - {0}", pathFolder[0]);

            byte slaveID = 4;
            ushort startAddress = 0x20c;
            ushort numOfPoints =  1;

            SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort(pathFolder[0],
                             9600,
                             Parity.None,
                             8,
                             StopBits.One);  
            try
            { 
                _serialPort.Open();

                ModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(
                    _serialPort);
                master.Transport.ReadTimeout = 300;
 
             ushort[] data = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveID, startAddress, numOfPoints);
                    
                foreach (int item in data)
                {
                    Console.Write("\r\n{0}", item);  // 17445
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":Connect process " + ex.StackTrace +
               "==>" + ex.Message);
            }
 
            Console.ReadLine();
 
        }
    }}
```

Comment: A little [mcve] would be nice! Please [edit] your question to include the code you're currently using to read from the device and the code you use to convert the read data to a float

Comment: @MindSwipe thanks for the amendment. Added code!

Comment: Skimming the documentation, the `ReadHoldingRegisters` reads the holding registers from the device, and the documentation also tells me that the holding registers contain unsigned shorts (16-bit whole number with a range from 0 to 65'535) not floats. Are you manually writing the floats into the registers? If so, please update your question with the code that does it, and if not, where is that data coming from?

Comment: @MindSwipe The device says that "Format: 32 bit floating point. Order:` ABCD` ". I do not have access to the instrument to change the data, so I am not recording anything.

Comment: Which device? The documentation I have (NModbus API Manual version 1.2, October 2013) simply states "Read holding registers value." and the method clearly returns a ushort array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226088/discussion-between-mindswipe-and-catsbreak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for.

```
            ushort[] received = new ushort[] { data[1], data[0] };
            byte[] asByte = new byte[4];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(received, 0, asByte, 0, 4);
            float result = BitConverter.ToSingle(asByte, 0); 
            Console.Write("Result-{0}", result);   // 660
```